# Firebase messages not saved in order flutter draft

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building basically a message app where the user can add a message (task), which will be saved in firebase. It should then be shown on the screen as "messagebubbles" in order (the newest one at the bottom of the screen). The messages don't show up in order though. Looking into my firebase database collection, it seems as if the messages are not saved in order of the time they arrived. Is that a normal behaviour and does that mean that I have to sort my snapshot instead? I thought the snapshot would show me the messages exactly in the same order as they were sent.

```
 TextField(
              controller: messageTextController,
              autofocus: true,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              cursorColor: Colors.white,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              onChanged: (newText) {
                newTaskTitle = newText;
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text(
                'Add',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: kSlate,
                ),
              ),
              color: kSlateBorder,
              onPressed: () {
                messageTextController.clear();
                firestore.collection('Slate1').add({
                  'Task': newTaskTitle,
                  'User': loggedInUser.email,
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),



Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore.collection('Test').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data['Task'];
          final messageSender = message.data['User'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );

          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document in Firestore are not naturally ordered by time.  In the console, they appear ordered by the document ID.

If you want to impose an ordering on documents within a collection, you should use a document field for that.  Consider adding a timestamp field to each message, then [order your query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) using that timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone else was looking for an answer / implementation:

here is how I added the firebase server timestamp

```
firestore.collection('Test1').add({
                  'Task': newTaskTitle,
                  'User': loggedInUser.email,
                  'Timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                });
```

and ordered it then here based on the timestamp:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore.collection('Test1').orderBy('Timestamp').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
```